# What is wrong with the lookup in my InfoPath Form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, lookup-column

I have SharePoint Online list which I am customizing with an InfoPath form. Two of the fields on the Form are lookup fields with a secondary Data Connection to a second SharePoint List with Fields Named `Funding Source` and `Income Code`.

When a `Funding Source` is selected from a DropDown list on the InfoPath form, the corresponding income Code should be populated in the `Income Code` text box.

I've created the Data Connection and set up the DropDown list so a `Funding Source` can be selected but the `Income Code` box is displaying the top code in the list regardless of which `Funding Source` is selected in the box.

I must have done something wrong in setting up the `Income Code` box.

Can someone provide me with a step by step plan of how to set up the income code box please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that the textbox used for Income Code is just pointing to the secondary data source field but doesn't have any filtering to show the Income code of the selected Funding Source. As there are multiple entries in the data source (all from the lookup list) it will show the first value.

Try setting the value of the Income code using a rule. Rough steps:

1. Create a new action rule on the dropdown (will fire every time it changes)
2. Action: Set field value.
3. Choose income code field.
4. For the value use "Insert Field or Group". Select the income code from your secondary source.
5. Click on the “Filter data” button and filter on Funding Source using the value selected in the DDL (main data source)

Comment: I've already got that rule created. 
The problem seems to be with the creation of the Filter. If I set both sides of the filter eqaution to the same field (Fund, IncomeCode or ID) the first income Code in the list displays regardless of which funding source is selected. 

Any other combination I've tried so far and the box remains blank

Answer (score 0):

Try creating this rule, put this on `Funding Source` field.

1. Create a rule, Condition is when `Funding Source` is not
   blank
2. Create action with set a field's value. For the Fields value, select fx button then go to the Secondary Data Connection drop then expand queryFields then select the `Funding Source` field. Click OK.
3. For the Value, select the `Funding Source` drop down. It will appear as (.) period.
4. After the first action step, add now another action step: the Query this Data Connection.
   Query your secondary Data Connection.
5. Now I expect that the `Income Code` field will just contain all the
   code that is matched with the `Funding Source` field selected.

Now every time the user selects a value in `Funding Source` field, it will send query the data connection based on the selected value and then the `Income Code` field will just display the results.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mATsK0aVZ9I , this video will help you achieve what you are looking for. I used the video to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://brainspire.com/how-to-pull-in-sharepoint-lookup-additional-fields-into-infopath-form/?unapproved=1775&moderation-hash=297cd63debebcddc145f4300fda195ec#comment-1775). I got it working for Calculated Field but to have lookup pull data to text box field, it only worked in preview but it wont load/stuck in the SharePoint.